# Factorial issue with user input

Tags: c, factorial

I am learning c language and i am confused about the code below. its a recursion but how come when i run this code, it won't run until i provided 2 different inputs but system only execute the first?

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

long factor (float user_input)
{
if(user_input <=1)
return 1;
else
return (user_input * factor (user_input - 1));
}

int main ()
{
int user_input;
long factorial_calculation;
printf("what factorial number would you like to calculate?\n");
scanf("%d\n", &user_calculation);
factorial_calculation = factor (user_input);
printf("ld\n", factorial_calculation);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is `user_calculation` defined ?

Comment: Can't test it at the moment, but it looks like the `\n` in the scanf format string is attempting to consume whitespace until the next non-whitespace character or EOF, which means it has to wait until either EOF or a non-whitespace character is encountered.

Comment: Note that [scanf does weird things with whitespace characters](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

Comment: Would be nice some indentation.

Comment: Thanks everyone, the \n was the cause of the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your `user_input` is `int` but you are passing variable as a `float` and running your factorial function on it. Factorials are undefined for non-integer nos, so you are better off using `int`.
2. In:

   ```
   printf("ld\n", factorial_calculation);
   ```

   `ld` is an invalid format specifer.
3. In

   ```
   scanf("%d\n", &user_calculation);
   ```

   I think you meant

   ```
   scanf("%d", &user_input);
   ```

The following code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int factor (int user_input)
{
    if(user_input <=1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (user_input * factor (user_input - 1));
}

int main ()
{
    int user_input;
    long factorial_calculation;
    printf("what factorial number would you like to calculate?\n");
    scanf("%d", &user_input);
    printf("%d\n",user_input);
    factorial_calculation = factor (user_input);
    printf("%d\n", factorial_calculation);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`scanf()` is notoriously difficult to synchronize with user input.  Instead, use `fgets()` and inspect the string for a number (or numbers if more than one is expected per line).

```
long factorial_calculation;
char buf [1000];
for (;;)
{
    printf("What factorial number would you like to calculate?\n");
    if (!fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin))  /* probably EOF, hangup, etc.:  just exit */
        return 0;
    if (1 != sscanf(buf, "%ld", &user_calculation))
    {
        printf ("No number entered, please try again\n");
        continue;
    }
    factorial_calculation = factor (user_input);
}
```

Comment: +1 for solid `fgets()` approach.  BTW: Any particular reason for `"%ld"` vs. OP's `"%d"`?